# Find Number of days in seasons range by providing from and to date

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-range

**Have implemented code for single season where date range doesn't overlap and it works fine**

Online PHP Code : https://onlinephp.io/c/1ca08

```
$ranges = array(
    'low' => array(
                    array( 'start' => "15 March 2023", 'end' => "15 May 2023") // 15 March - 15 May
                ),
    'high' => array(
                    array( 'start' => "16 May 2023", 'end' => "30 June 2023"), // 16 May - 16 June
                    array( 'start' => "1 July 2023", 'end' => "14 March 2024")
                ),
    'winter' => array(
                    array( 'start' => "1 December 2023", 'end' => "15 March 2023")
                ),
    'summer' => array(
                    array( 'start' => "1 June 2023", 'end' => "30 August 2023")
                    )
            );
             
             
// High Season Inputs 
$start_date = '2023-05-17'; // 17 May 2023
$end_date =   '2023-05-25'; // 25 May 2023
// ----- OUTPUT - Working -----------------------------------
// [high] Season and no.of nights: 8

// Low Season Inputs 
// $start_date = '2023-03-16'; // 16 March 2023
// $end_date =   '2023-03-21'; // 21 March 2023
// ----- OUTPUT - Working -----------------------------------
// [low] Season and no.of nights: 5

// Summer Season Inputs 
// $start_date = '2023-06-01'; // 01 June 2023
// $end_date =   '2023-06-10'; // 10 June 2023
// ----- OUTPUT - Working -----------------------------------
// [summer] Season and no.of nights: 5

// Overlap season Low to High - 
// $start_date = '2023-05-12'; // 12 May 2023
// $end_date =   '2023-05-18'; // 18 May 2023
// ----- OUTPUT -----------------------------------
// [low] Season and no.of nights: 4
// [high] Season and no.of nights: 2

// Overlap season High to Low - 4 in high + 5 in low
// $start_date = '2023-03-11'; // 11 March 2023
// $end_date =   '2023-03-20'; // 20 March 2023
// ----- OUTPUT -----------------------------------
// [low] Season and no.of nights: 4
// [high] Season and no.of nights: 5

// Overlap multiple season 
// $start_date = '2023-05-12'; // 12 May 2023
// $end_date =   '2023-06-10'; // 10 June 2023
// ----- OUTPUT -----------------------------------
// [low] Season and no.of nights: 4
// [high] Season and no.of nights: 26
// [summer] Season and no.of nights: 9

$i = 1;
foreach($ranges as $key => $single_range) {
    
    foreach($single_range as $range) {
        $date1 = new DateTime($start_date);
        $date2 = new DateTime($end_date);
        $totalnumberOfNights= $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
        
        $date_range_start   =  new DateTime($range['start']);
        $date_range_end     =  new DateTime($range['end']);

        
        if ( ( ( (strtotime( $start_date ) >= strtotime( $range['start'] ) ) && ( strtotime( $end_date ) <= strtotime( $range['end'] ) ) ) ) ) {
            $no_of_season_night = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
            
            echo "$i-) The selected dates exists in [$key] Season and no.of nights in this range: [$no_of_season_night] = $totalnumberOfNights \n";

        }
  
    }
     $i++;
}
```

Have implemented code for single season where date range doesn't overlap and it works fine.

I need someone to help me find multiple season nights in a specific date range.
LIKE if user input are

- $start_date = '2023-05-12'; // 12 May 2023
- $end_date =   '2023-06-10'; // 10 June 2023
- [low] Season and no.of nights: 4
- [high] Season and no.of nights: 26
- [summer] Season and no.of nights: 9
  Thanks In Advanced :)

Comment: How do we count `15 March 2023`, it is in two ranges? Why don't all of the ranges flow in the same direction? Winter goes backward in time. What happens when an input date is not in one of the ranges? Just ignore it?

Comment: Also, how are you counting those no. of nights?